# post a link of a page

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post via application a link of a page on user's wall but it seems impossible to modify description, name and image who are those of the page and not those I want.

```
$publishStream=$facebook->api("/$user/links",'post',
   array(
    'message' => "my message"
    'link'    => "LINK OF A PAGE EX.: https://www.facebook.com/pages/xxxxx,
    'name'    => "my link name",
    'description'=> "my description", 
    'type' => 'link'
    )
);
```

Output: a link with description  of page and not my description, image of page and not my image, name of page and not my link name.

Answer (score 0):

Try without a "type" parameter. Once this fixed my similar problem.